# Printf not working properly, Keeps duplicating nextline

Tags: java, arrays

Here's the source code of my problem.
https://pastebin.com/MEwtrxgU.. in the line of `System.out.printf("Enter Birthday in Month/Day/Year: "); bday[z] = console.next();` i cannot input the birthday because the nextline of code keeps inserting.

```
if (choice.equals("s")){
            System.out.println("Enter Login Details");
            System.out.printf("Enter Username: ");
            uname[z] = console.next();
            System.out.printf("Enter Password: ");
            pword[z] = console.next();
            System.out.printf("Enter your Full Name: ");
            name[z] = console.next();
            System.out.printf("Enter Birthday in Month/Day/Year: ");
            bday[z] = console.next();

            System.out.printf("Enter Grade for Programming (2 Units): ");
            subjects[z][0] = consoleDouble.nextDouble();
            System.out.printf("Enter Grade for Computing (3 Units): ");
            subjects[z][1] = consoleDouble.nextDouble();
            System.out.printf("Enter Grade for UTS (3 Units): ");
            subjects[z][2] = consoleDouble.nextDouble();
            System.out.printf("Enter Grade for STS (3 Units): ");
            subjects[z][3] = consoleDouble.nextDouble();
            System.out.printf("Enter Grade for PE (2 Units): ");
            subjects[z][4] = consoleDouble.nextDouble();
            z++;
        }
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Fullname is going to have spaces in it, so next, will take the first word, and then the next `next` will take the next.  Use `nextLine` and then split

Answer (score 1):

Your problem in your input before the line where you see your bug. If you want to read several words also you have to put several `console.next()`.
Official document says:

> A Scanner breaks its input into tokens using a delimiter pattern,
>   which by default matches whitespace.
>   Method next() finds and returns
>   the next complete token from this scanner. A complete token is
>   preceded and followed by input that matches the delimiter pattern.
>   This method may block while waiting for input to scan, even if a
>   previous invocation of hasNext() returned true.

Hope it helps. You can see more on oracle docs website.

Answer (score 1):

Replacing the `console.next()` with `console.nextLine()` will resolve your issue.

`next()` returns only what comes before a delimiter (defaults to whitespace).

> **public String next()**
>   Finds and returns the next complete token from this scanner. A complete token is preceded and followed by input that matches the delimiter pattern. This method may block while waiting for input to scan, even if a previous invocation of hasNext() returned true.

`nextLine()` moves the scanner down only after returning the current line.

> **public String nextLine()**
>   Advances this scanner past the current line and returns the input that was skipped. This method returns the rest of the current line, excluding any line separator at the end. The position is set to the beginning of the next line.
>
> Since this method continues to search through the input looking for a line separator, it may buffer all of the input searching for the line to skip if no line separators are present.

Official Page - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Answer (score 0):

Do this

```
System.out.printf("Enter your Full Name: ");
name[z] = console.nextLine();
```

`next` will stop as soon as a `space` is encountered. `nextLine` will take till `line break`.